# gedit broken shortcut keys, has mod2

Tags: gedit

I have been trying to play around with gedit and came across the "shortcut editor" plugin. But somehow, it messed up my key bindings. It no longer works. Everytime I try to setup a new shortcut, I get a "Mod2" addition to the bind.

How do I reset to the default key bindings? How do I remove Mod2?

Thanks,

Wenbert

EDIT:
Google does not seem to return any relevant results regarding this issue.

Comment: IMO, this question should be on superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my question. I have solved it after hours of trial and error.

I was connecting to my Linux machine running gedit using Synergy. So I jsut transfered the keyboard to the USB port running the linux machine and then reconfigured the Shortcut Editor Plugin for gedit.

The shortcuts are now properly set by the plugin.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but I solved it by toggling off the numlock

Comment: Definitely better answer! Set numlock off in editing shortcuts, for normal use of gedit it is not necessary. Thank you.